# How to add a complex label with italics and a variable to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, geom-text

I have read many postings on this topic using `expression()`, `paste()`, and `bquote()`, or some combination. I think I am close to solving my problem, but I just can't get there. The following script generates a plot labelled with "y = 1 + 2(x); r^2= 0.9". How can I italicize "y" and "x", and italicize the "r" and superscript the 2 of "r^2"? If I have overlooked a relevant earlier post, sorry, but please direct me to it.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(1:5))
a <- 1    
b <- 2
r2 <- 0.9
eq <- paste("y = ", a, " + ", b, "(x); r^2=", r2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point(color="black")+
  geom_text(x=2, y=4,label=eq, parse=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `annotate()` which allows you to paste directly into the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(color="black") +
  annotate('text', 2.5, 4, 
           label=paste("italic(y)==", a, "+", b, 
                       "~italic(x)~';'~italic(r)^2==", r2), 
           parse=TRUE, 
           hjust=1, size=5)
```

*Yields:*

[image]

*Data:*

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(1:5))
a <- 1
b <- 2
r2 <- 0.9
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `substitute` and `plotmath` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.5.1/topics/plotmath) to italicize the text-

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)

# dataframe
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(1:5))

# label
eq <- substitute(
  expr =
    paste(
      italic("y"),
      " = ",
      a,
      " + ",
      b,
      "(",
      italic("x"),
      "); ",
      italic("r") ^ 2,
      " = ",
      r2
    ),
  env = base::list(a = 1,
                   b = 2,
                   r2 = 0.9)
)

# plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(color = "black") +
  labs(subtitle = eq)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by [Indrajit Patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7973626/indrajeet-patil) & [jay-sf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6574038/jay-sf), I would like to add that there is an automated way to fit regression lines (I believe there are many), using a package called [ggpmisc](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/reference/stat_poly_eq.html). The letters that you want in italic, are already formatted in such a way. The code that needs to be used is:

```
> install.packages('ggpmisc'); library(ggpmisc); formula <- y ~ x
> df <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(1:5))
> ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(color="black") + 
       geom_smooth(method =   "lm", formula = formula) + 
       stat_poly_eq(aes(label =   paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),
       formula = formula, parse = TRUE)
```

It shows the fitted lines also, which I hope is not an impediment to the main goal.
[image: fitting line with equation]

> EDIT: The line can be removed using `linetype = 0`, compatible with
>   most of the `aesthetics` in `ggplot2`.

```
... + geom_smooth(method =   "lm", formula = formula, linetype = 0) + ...
```